# How can i get a database view which has foreign keys changed in the real value?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i'm not so good in programming, and i've to make this fix in my code, which basically has 2 tables (players: ID, name,password ; match: player_ID, attack, level)connected by primary and foreign keys. I've to retrieve an output which contains the player_ID changed with the real player name. I know how it works at db-level, but now i'm using JDBC to interact with the Mysql database. I've understood that i've to manipulate the db-metadata, but i still have not understood with which method and overall the logic behind.

Comment: Are you saying that in your ResultSet (recordset) you want to see user name instead of user ID?
In your `select` statement specify `players.name` (and you may want to keep `players.ID` too)

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC API will take an arbitrary query so all you have to do is join the tables and get match information along with player name.

```
select m.attack, m.level, p.name from match m inner join player p on m.player_ID = p.ID
```